# second session automatically creating in php

Tags: php, session

I have a problem, I created two login pages, stlogin.php and adlogin.php; stslogin.php moves to student.php and adlogin.php moves to admin.php. When I login to stlogin.php then a session start and it heads to student.php, but the problem is that when I CHANGE link and type admin.php at address bar this one also opens. What is the problem with that? Why does it access admin.php?

adlogin.php page is

```
<?php

require('connect.inc.php');
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();

 $sessadid = $_SESSION['id'];
 $sessadname = $_SESSION['name'];
 $sessadusername = $_SESSION['username'];
 $sessadpassword = $_SESSION['password'];
 $sessademail = $_SESSION['email'];
 $sessadcourse = $_SESSION['course'];

?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['username'])||isset($_POST['password'])){
$username= htmlentities($_POST['username']);
$password1= htmlentities($_POST['password']);
$password= md5($password1);
$query= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
$numrow = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrow == 0){
    $error = 'Please enter correct username';
    }else if($numrow == 1){
        $run = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $dbid =$run['id'];
            $dbname =$run['name'];
            $dbusername =$run['username'];
            $dbpassword =$run['password'];
            $dbemail =$run['email'];
            $dbcourse =$run['course'];

            if($password === $dbpassword){
                $_SESSION['id'] = $dbid;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $dbname;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $dbpassword;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $dbemail;
                $_SESSION['course'] = $dbcourse;

                header('Location: admin.php');
                }else{
                    $error = 'password does not match';
                    }

        }
    }

?>
```

my admin.php page is

```
<?php

require('connect.inc.php');
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();

$sessadid = $_SESSION['id'];
$sessadname = $_SESSION['name'];
$sessadusername = $_SESSION['username'];
$sessadpassword = $_SESSION['password'];
$sessademail = $_SESSION['email'];
$sessadcourse = $_SESSION['course'];

?>

<?php
if($sessadid && $sessadpassword && $sessadusername){
echo 'admin page';
}else{
header('Location:adlogin.php');
}
```

my stlogin.php page is

```
<?php

require('connect.inc.php');
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();

$sessid = $_SESSION['id'];
$sessreg = $_SESSION['reg'];
$sessname = $_SESSION['name'];
$sessusername = $_SESSION['username'];
$sesspassword = $_SESSION['password'];
$sessemail = $_SESSION['email'];
$sesscourse = $_SESSION['course'];
$sessimg = $_SESSION['image'];

?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username'])||isset($_POST['password'])){
$username= htmlentities($_POST['username']);
$password1= htmlentities($_POST['password']);
$password= md5($password1);
$query= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
$numrow = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrow == 0){
    $error = 'Please enter correct username';
    }else if($numrow == 1){
        $run = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $dbid =$run['id'];
            $dbname =$run['name'];
            $dbusername =$run['username'];
            $dbpassword =$run['password'];
            $dbemail =$run['email'];
            $dbcourse =$run['course'];
            $dbreg =$run['reg'];
            $dbimg =$run['image'];

            if($password === $dbpassword){
                $_SESSION['id'] = $dbid;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $dbname;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $dbpassword;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $dbemail;
                $_SESSION['course'] = $dbcourse;
                $_SESSION['reg'] = $dbreg;
                $_SESSION['image'] = $dbimg;

                header('Location: student.php');
                }else{
                    $error = 'password does not match';
                    }

        }
}

?>
```

my student.php page is

```
<?php

require('connect.inc.php');
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();

$sessid = $_SESSION['id'];
$sessreg = $_SESSION['reg'];
$sessname = $_SESSION['name'];
$sessusername = $_SESSION['username'];
$sesspassword = $_SESSION['password'];
$sessemail = $_SESSION['email'];
$sesscourse = $_SESSION['course'];
$sessimg = $_SESSION['image'];

?>


if($sessid && $sessname && $sesspassword){
echo 'student page';
}else{
header('Location: stlogin.php');
}
```

Comment: Why? Hard to say. "Why" don't you show us what you're using for code.

Comment: Define different [`session.name`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name)'s for those 2, so they won't clash. But best also have a different storage location for those 2 (otherwise, some handy people might change the name in the cookie and still be granted access).

Comment: got solution thanks a lot to all

Comment: You can also add a `is_admin` flag to your session array when logging in. That is particularly useful if your `admins` are a subset of your `users`.